# Why does layout builder duplicate the body of a node after a full configuration import?

Tags: 9, configuration, layout-builder

I used Layout builder for a site (Site A) using Drupal 9 and configured the Article content type to

- Use Layout Builder and
- Allow each content item to have its layout customized

This allowed me to customize each article node page whenever is needed. While this module is working as epxected in Site A, exporting and importing all the site configuration to a new Drupal site (Site B) creates the following issues on the aritcle nodes.

1. The body of the article node is rendered twice
2. Any block added to the article node using the Layoutbuilder UI is rendered twice.

Other content types are not affected since they are not configured to use the Layoutbuilder. Issue only affects the Article content type and no error message displayed when importing the configuration. Clearing the cache in Site B doesnt make any difference. Please see attached screenshot of the Layout for the content type Article for the two sites, side by side.

My question is, is this a known bug in the layout builder or Drupal configu sync? if so how can I resolve the duplication of fields in the destination site?

Any advise how i can overcome this issue will be greatly apprciated.

Drupal: 9.4.8
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a question-and-answer site. What is your question? This looks like a bug report.

Comment: Can you confirm that you imported the entire configuration of one site into another, existing site, a site that was installed separately, resulting in duplicated entities?

Comment: Yes I exported SiteA full configuration and import to SiteB - all configuration. After that, all the article fields are rended twice. This is noticed only on the Article content type which its display mode uses the Layout builder.

Comment: Drupal has built-in protections against importing another site’s configuration, because it is not a supported action. How did you overcome them?

Comment: SiteA and SiteB are same site with same salt. Its dev and staging enviroment running on simialr databases backups